How to read this statement? $f: \mathbb{Z}\to\mathbb{R}: f(x)= ( x^2+1)/2$
I am interested in how we can read this statement regarding a function.
Is it just as it is, or maybe $(x^2 + 1)$ is a divisor for $2$?
Or is it just a bracket divided by $2$, meaning we just have to plug in the values?
Straight from the task word file:
Can You define it?
$f: \mathbb{Z} \to  \mathbb{R}$  by $ f(x)= ( x^2+1)/2$  find $f( A)$ where $A = \{ 3,5,6\}$
and $f^{-1}(B)$ where $B = \{ 1, 5/8, 0\}$

I'd expect it is division by 2, but you can't be sure

Can you maybe take a picture of the statement? Or provide more information?

$x$ is an integer(can take value all values from $-\infty$ to $\infty$ in, increments of 1). In other words,$x \in \mathbb{Z}$. $f(x)$ is a function that takes in as an argument $x$ and produces a real number (thus, the image of $f$ is a set of values that is a subset of $\mathbb{R}$) that is computed by $\frac{(x^2 + 1)}{2}$., Most certainly. Can you prove that the real is always positive?

$x^2+1$ being divisor of $2$ would be a statement (true/false), so it does not make sense on the right side of $f(x)=$, you expect an expression/real number there. So it's just $x^2+1$ divided by $2$.

Unless there is some unusual context, you just "plug in the values". The output will be an integer just when the input integer is odd.

$f: \mathbb{Z}\to\mathbb{R}: f(x)= ( x^2+1)/2$
You have to read this by $f$, a function from the set of all integers to the set of all real numbers defined as $(x^{2}+1)$ divided by $2$.
If you want to see the function: If $n = 2k$, then $f(2k) = 2k^{2} + 0.5$ and if $n = 2k+1$, then $f(2k+1) = 2k^{2} + 2k + 1$.
For your next question:
If $A = \{ 3,5,6\}$ then $f(A) = \{5,13,18.5\}$ and $f^{-1}(1) = \{1,-1\}$, $f^{-1}(0) = \phi$ and also $f^{-1}(5/8) = \phi$, as $f^{-1}(0) = \{1/4,-1/4\}$ not a subset of $\mathbb{Z}$. So $f^{-1}(B) = \{1,-1\}$ where $B = \{ 1, 5/8, 0\}$
